# Error when uploading file to FTP server using My.Computer.Network.UploadFile

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftp-client

I am using this code to upload / download files from my FTP server

```
  //Download
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(txtFile, localFilePath, userName, pw)

  //Upload
    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(localFilePath, txtFile, userName, pw)
```

The download is working perfectly. The upload line throws a WebException though.

This is kind of weird since I'm using the same variables in both requests.

Any idea what the reason for this could be? 
Thanks

Comment: What `WebException`? What are the actual values of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

Was connected to my university wifi. Apparently this function doesn't work with proxys